# English fonts displayed RTL and mirrored in Hebrew document

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, microsoft-word-2013

Word-2013 displaying English fonts mirrored and RTL-ed when opening a word document containing English and Hebrew fonts.

Example: NET Framework (LTR) while it is displayed as krowemarF TEN

I created a macro script that does the following:

```
Sub LTR_RUN()
     Application.Run MacroName:="LtrRun"
End Sub
```

Which solves the issue until the next time I'm opening the document.
Any ideas how to cope with this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, any support ?